# An ablity to see when I have voted

Tags: feature-request

I often come across questions I have seen before and answers that have helped me already (and I can see this because the up-arrows are orange).

Then I wonder *Hey, I should have remembered this! Was this a long time ago?*. But when I hover the arrow, there is no such info.

[image]

If I click it to undo (and the answer has not been edited since I had voted), the information is shown:

[image]

But if the answer has been edited, there is no way to find out (besides scrolling the *votes* tab in your profile which is rather uncomfortable).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: In which way is that information important for you?

Comment: Important? No. Interesting. I can prove myself that I do copypaste programming too often. Or, if it was long time ago, I can justify myself looking for the same information again. *I could have forgotten this in 2 years!* :-)